# How to create Token from payment card for future use in Stripe Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, stripe-payments

I have an app where the user enters his credit card infos when signing up (card number,cvc,expiration month/year), and I want to create a token with these informations and use it later in the app for payments, I am using the flutter_stripe package, I know it was possible in the stripe_payment package, but I can't find the way to do with the new package flutter_stripe.

Comment: I don't think the flutter_stripe package is relevant here, since saving and reusing payment methods with Stripe would be a backend affair. Namely, you would set `setup_future_usage=off_session` on the initial Payment Intent to save the card when it gets confirmed in the app, then create and confirm Payment Intents entirely from the backend using the saved payment method and `off_session=true`. So there is no change to the frontend workflow. See https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment for details.